# Getting <@[object Object]>! error when creating first HelloWorld bot in Slack / Bolt

Tags: node.js, slack, bolt

I'm trying to create my first HelloWorld bot following this official tutorial using Bolt (https://api.slack.com/tutorials/hello-world-bolt).

The code is almost unchanged from the tutorial (only changed 'hello world' to 'hello bae'), however the User name is not being returned properly.

Can someone spot the issue? Thankyou so much in advance!

[image]

Bug in Slack:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code shared above, you have created a new object `user` with properties `user` & `channel`.

Therefore, the correct syntax would be :
`` say(`Hello bae, and welcome <@${user.user}>!`); ``

Comment: Thankyou so much Suyash, this worked perfectly! A little strange that the official Slack Tutorial had this error in it, but you've saved me :)